# Why doesn't OnCollisionStay execute continuously?

Tags: c#, unity

I'm currently trying to build a simple demo where the player can jump. This is the script I have setup so far.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 jumpForce;

    void OnCollisionStay (Collision other)
    {
        print("OnCollisionStay");
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space) && other.gameObject.tag == "Block")
        {
            rigidbody.velocity += jumpForce;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I check the console, the message `"OnCollisionStay"` is only printed 21 times. Just for more details the GameObject this script is attached to contains a rigidbody that uses gravity, has the x, y, and z rotation axes frozen, and the z position axis forzen as well. The gameObject I'm trying to collide with has a simple box collider attached to a cube with a scale of `(5, 1, 5)`. What am I doing wrong? I am under the impression that `OnCollisionStay` continuously executes until the player is no longer colliding with anything, then starts executing again on collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the object is at rest and the Rigidbody has been put to sleep.

You can modify [`Rigidbody.sleepThreshold`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-sleepThreshold.html) to change this behaviour for a single instance.

Alternatively you can change the threshold project wide via the [Physics Manager](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html).  Try setting "Sleep Threshold"/"Sleep Velocity" to zero.